# PHP, как внутри класса получить request?

Tags: php, классы, request

Подскажите как получить request данные внутри класса? Это нужно в свойствах указывать или где-то в функциях прописывать?

```
class IncludeRequest
{
    public $_type;
    public static $el;
    public static $sec;
    private $hash;


 public $emk;

 public $emk2;


    function __construct($params)
    {
        self::$el = new CIBlockElement;
        self::$sec = new CIBlockSection;


        $emk = intval($_GET['emk']);
        $emk2 = intval($_GET['emk2']);


//Даем возможность указать тип из вне
        if ($params['_type']) {
            $this->_type = $params['_type'];
        }

        if ($this->_type) {
            $methodName = 'request_' . $this->_type;
            $fparams = $params['_params'] ? $params['_params'] : false;

            if ($fparams) {
                $this->{$methodName}($fparams);
            } else {
                $this->{$methodName}();
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Как здесь я описал , это не работает.

Comment: По моему проще засовывать в конструктор URL строку и там же её разбирать.

Comment: какой request-то?

Comment: @Etki судя по его коду, он хочет получить GET параметры в классе.

Comment: @temaror Объясните, какая ваша конечная цель? Может быть, если вы ее сформулируете, я смогу Вам помочь.

Comment: В функции этого класса есть параметры, эти параметры нужно менять постоянно. Например где написано 140 его постоянно необходимо менять. $arFilter = $params['arFilter'];
  $arFilter['IBLOCK_ID'] = 140;
  $arFilter[] = 
  array(
   "LOGIC"=>"OR",
   array(
    "!PROPERTY_AUTHOR"=>false,
    ),
   array(
    "!CREATED_BY"=>false
    ),
   );

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решил это тем что в каждой функции писал прием $_REQUEST['emk'], и дальше выводил в параметрах $arFilter['IBLOCK_ID'] = $emk;, например:

```
function request_p($params = false)
{
    $emk = intval($_REQUEST['emk']);
    $emk2 = intval($_REQUEST['emk2']);;
    $el = new CIBlockElement;
    $arFilter = $params['arFilter'];
    $arFilter['IBLOCK_ID'] = $emk;
    $arFilter[] = 
    array(
        "LOGIC"=>"OR",
        array(
            "!PROPERTY_AUTHOR"=>false,
            ),
        array(
            "!CREATED_BY"=>false
            ),
        );
```

f